# Remove span tags from product name in Woocommerce My Account Downloads

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, download, hook-woocommerce, product-variations

I have problem with my woocommerce downloads section on WooCommerce "my account" > "Downloads": On product variations name, there is a `<span>` html tag that are visible:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIg0X.png]

I have tried to remove those "span" tags using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_available_downloads', 'remove_span_dl_name', 10, 7);
function remove_span_dl_name( $download ){
    return str_replace( '<span> - </span>', ' - ',$download['download_name']);
}
```

but it removes all downloads altogether.

And I have also tried to remove those "span" tags using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_download_link', 'remove_span_dl_name', 10, 7);
function remove_span_dl_name( $download ){
    return str_replace( '<span> - </span>', ' - ',$download['download_name'] );
}
```

What is my mistake and how can I get rid of these tags?

Answer (score 0):

The hook `woocommerce_available_download_link` is included in `myaccount/my-downloads.php` deprecated template since WooCommerce version 2.6 (the right template file that is used is `myaccount/downloads.php`).

Now as downloads are loaded through `WC_Customer` method `get_downloadable_products()`, [you can to use `woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products` filter hook](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.1/includes/class-wc-customer.php#L224) included in this method. Or also `woocommerce_customer_available_downloads` filter hook too.

To remove tags from product name, you can use `str_replace()` or much better and efficient `strip_tags()`:

**1). First way** - Using `strip_tags()` function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products', 'remove_span_tags_from_product_name' );
// Or also
// add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_available_downloads', 'remove_span_tags_from_product_name' );
function remove_span_tags_from_product_name( $downloads ){
    // Only on my account downloads section
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url('downloads') )
        return $downloads;

    // Loop though downloads
    foreach( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
        // remove "span" html tags
        $downloads[$key]['product_name'] = strip_tags( $download['product_name'] );
    }
    return $downloads;
}
```

**2). Another way** - Using `str_replace()` function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products', 'remove_span_tags_from_product_name' );
// Or also
// add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_available_downloads', 'remove_span_tags_from_product_name' );
function remove_span_tags_from_product_name( $downloads ){
    // Only on my account downloads section
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url('downloads') )
        return $downloads;

    // Loop though downloads
    foreach( $downloads as $key => $download ) {
        // remove "span" html tags
        $downloads[$key]['product_name'] = str_replace( array('<span>', '</span>'), array('', ''), $download['product_name'] );
    }
    return $downloads;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Any way should work.

> If you want that to work also everywhere ("order view", "Order received", emails notifications), remove:
>
> ```
> // Only on my account downloads section
> if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url('downloads') )
>     return $downloads;
> ```

Comment: OH MY GAWD its working! Thanks A LOT!!! Аnd after so many hours of searching for answers, and looking at the code on similar topics. The sight of your code is simply pleasing to the eye. Also i have not even seen any mention of this hook anywhere.